# git: what does "fatal: Failed to execute internal merge" mean?

Tags: git

I just ran `git merge otherBranch` and it output this error to the command line:

```
fatal: Failed to execute internal merge
```

What could this mean? I would give more details, but I'm not sure what details would be important. Have other people experienced this, and if so what caused it in your case?

EDIT:

It looks like this is a catch-all error message. However, if other people have found specific reasons for failure and think others might benefit from the solution you found, feel free to post those as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source of `git`:

```
        merge_status = merge_3way(o, &result_buf, one, a, b,
                      branch1, branch2);

        if ((merge_status < 0) || !result_buf.ptr)
            die("Failed to execute internal merge");
```

`merge_3way` is the function which (unsurprisingly) performs a three-way merge. So, the "failed to execute internal merge" message is printed any time the merge returns an error.

You almost certainly had *another* error message above the one you posted, which is the real cause.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also curious if a failure here would either 1) rollback all successful merges done prior 2) leave in working directory whatever changes were merged prior to failure or 3) finish all changes before/after failure and keep those in working directory.

Comment: @Thr4wn Since you seem to have a situation where you can test, you're welcome to try. Regardless of which of the three it is, since your repository is intact and you're likely using `rerere`, you won't have an issue.

Comment: For future googlers: when I get this error, git simply aborts mid-stroke and leaves the index and working directory right as it was during the moment of failure.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was causing by a conflict in very large binary file.

`git merge <branch-goes-here> -s resolve` correctly merged and afterwards reported the merge-conflict, allowing for manual fixing the merge-conflict as usual.